# Dynamically Image update doesn't work in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mozilla

I have set an image in jsp as

```
 <img  id="captcha" src= "/app/img.servlet"  onclick="reloadImg();" />
```

This will call appropriate servlet and show the result.Clicking on this image,servlet would be  recalled and new image will be generated.To display on page I use below method

```
function reloadImg(){
$("#captcha").attr("src", "/app/img.servlet");
```

}

This seems working fine on chrome but doesn't work on mozilla. Couldn't find out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding time in my calling url solved my problem.

```
function reloadImg(){
var d = new Date();
$("#captcha").attr("src", "/app/img.servlet?"+d.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling it on ready ?

For images it has to check for DOM ready

```
$(function (){
       //your code goes here 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write complete jquery function like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".signup-info_class",function() {
        var d = new Date();
        $('#captcha_image').attr('src',"jcaptcha.jpg?"+d.getTime());
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML code would be like :

```
<img id="captcha_image" src="jcaptcha.jpg" height="40" width="122"/>
<img src="images/refresh_image.jpg" class="signup-info_class"
                                    alt="reload" width="40" height="40" />
```